# rails namespace nomethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a few models, including `acts` , `bibliography` , `authors`. Trying to organise routes so that administrative actions on those models are grouped together under `namespace` administration.

This is my routes.rb:

```
namespace :administration do
  resources :actes, path: 'actes', path_names: { new: 'nouveau', edit: 'editer' }, except: [:chercher, :voir]
  get 'actes/nouveau/:id' => 'actes#nouveau', as: 'nouvel_acte'
  post 'actes/nouveau/:id' => 'actes#ajouter'
end
```

My controller has this :

```
class Administration::ActesController < ApplicationController

  def nouveau
    @titre = "Fons - ajouter un acte"
    @bib = Biblio.find(params[:id])
    @bibid = @bib.id
  end
```

In nouveau.html.erb I do this :

```
<% @bib.auteurs.each do |l| %>
  <%= l.nom_complet %>, 
<% end %>
<%= @bib.titre %>, <%= @bib.lieu %>, <%= @bib.annee %>
```

This provokes a NoMethodError : `undefined method 'auteurs'`. I turns out that the entire method @bib is not know - although it works fine in rails console.

Comment: what's the url you're going to?

Comment: All this code is before the form, so the url to which the form posts shouldn't impact this (or am I missing something ?)

Comment: you're finding `biblio` via params, so that is coming from some request to your controller...

Comment: Is the `Biblio.find` line returning nil? Is the whole error message something like "undefined method 'auteurs' for nil"? It may just be failing to find a Biblio object.

Comment: @thiebo the problem is coming from this line `@bib = Biblio.find(params[:id])` .. try to debug after this line.. your `@bib` variable is `nil`

Comment: @sa77 if `@bib` was `nil` then it would've failed on `@bibid = @bib.id`.

Comment: @thiebo Can you post the output in `rails console` and the model `Biblio` ?

Comment: Thanks all !!2.3.1 :001 > Biblio
 => Biblio (call 'Biblio.connection' to establish a connection) 
2.3.1 :002 > Biblio.find(1)
  Biblio Load (28.5ms)  SELECT  "biblios".* FROM "biblios" WHERE "biblios"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Biblio id: 1, titre: "La vie urbaine à Douai au Moyen-Âge", soustitre: "T. III", editeur: "Picard", isbn: "", genre: "source", recueil: "", revue_id: nil, revue_no: nil, revue_page: "", annee: 1913, lieu: "Paris", commentaire: "", utilisateur_id: nil, created_at: "2017-01-11 18:40:50", updated_at: "2017-01-11 18:40:50">

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1. `@bib` object is `nil`, so you get an undefined method error for `NilClass`.
2. You don't have a relation between `Bibliography` and `Auteur` classes. You should have a statement in the first class with something like `has_many :auteurs`.

If you can paste here the whole error message I could be more specific. Hope this helps!